# React: audio element only plays once when I click the parent

Tags: reactjs, audio, html5-audio

As part of a React component, in the render function, I have audio elements as child of another elements.

```
<td onClick={this.handlePick}>

</td>
<td onClick={this.handlePick}>
</td>
 ...
```

Constructor and handlePick in the component are:

```
 constructor(props){
    ...
    this.state={
            url: '' 
          }
     }

handlePick(e){
    const option=e.target.id;
    const mySound=sounds[option] // sounds is array of url pointing to diferent sounds
    this.setState(()=>{
            return {
                url: mySound
                }
            }
        )

    const audio= new Audio(mySound)
    audio.play()
   }
```

When clicking any td element(parent of audio element) works  well, but if I click a second time it doesn't work. I need to click another td element to be able to click the previous one (only once).

Comment: Is that the complete code? How did the `<td>` get the `id` the handler is using?

Comment: I sorted by getting rid of the html audio element and creating a object with new Audio(mySound) in the handlePick() function. So, I can apply the method play() to that object every time the function is triggered.